# SonarQube Inspectcode/Resharper plugin result is not matching with Visual Studio Inspection

Tags: sonarqube, resharper, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I have been using the same set of rules defined in DotSettings files.

I have set this file under resharper \ manage options. Also when I am running InspectCode.exe I have provided the same.

I am using resharper plugin that comes with default rulesets repository and we have activated all those rules. (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/ReSharper+Plugin)

However, the result is not matching between SonarQube and Visual Studio.

Any idea what is going wrong here please?

Here are the stats screen shots.

Visual Studio shows 39 issues - 2 for web.config = 37 issues in total.

[image]

In SonarQube, using MSBuild.Runner and Resharper plugin is 32 violations.

Why there is a difference when I am download dotsettings file from the sonarqube and using the same for inspection in sonarqube as well as visual studio?

[image]

SonarQube Version Details:

- SonarQube: 5.4
- Resharper Plugin: 2.0
- C# Plugin: 5.2 (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin)

In case of sonarqube I know all details about version and stuff. But in case of Visual Studio all I know is the Resharper plugin version. Thus, I don't why there is any difference.

Comment: Any direction is welcome

Answer (score 1):

This is due to an open issue that jetbrains hasn't resolved yet (and as of now has no plans of resolving).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-463819